# Unable to run sudo dpkg --configure -a on fresh 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

Fresh install (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) I'm unable to update or install anything via `apt`. I can run `apt update` fine but if I follow that with either `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` it *always* (I've tried doing so after countless reboots, as well as from recovery mode) results in:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

If I run that it always does the following and just hangs indefinitely:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
```

`uname -r` shows it's running `4.10.0-35-generic` so I'd be fine removing `4.10.0-28-generic` since that's where it always hangs but I'm unable to purge it because that just results in `apt purge` hanging when it gets to `Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic`.

I've tried every possible ordering of the following without success

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade|dist-upgrade|full-upgrade
```

This is a fresh install so I'm not worried about any "nuclear" options that would result in data loss (i.e. I have no data to lose). I have tried using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but it never completed (it said it may take a few minutes but I left it running for hours).

I realize the similarities between this question and both [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a) and [dpkg --configure -a hangs when found initrd image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712361/dpkg-configure-a-hangs-when-found-initrd-image) but none of the answers have helped.

Comment: Use `apt` instead of `apt-get` and `full-upgrade` instead of `dist-upgrade` for any 16.04+. Now, reboot. Then run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade` and [edit] and post the full error messages if any.

Comment: My understanding is that there isn't a _difference_ between running `apt` vs `apt-get` but nevertheless I have been running `apt`, the code block above with the apt-gets was copied from a [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1888738), but I'll edit so it shows `apt`. As for `full-upgrade` that results in the same error as `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` (the `dpkg was interrupted...` one shown near the top of my question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there was an issue with 30_os-prober hanging during grub update. I forget exactly what the issue is.

30_uefi-firmware also has an issue that can be fixed here - https://askubuntu.com/a/938472/694267.

Temporarily remove the execute flag on both can get your config completed.
`sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
`sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware`

then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

If you want the system setting entry in grub, repair 30_uefi-firmware then re-enable execute with
`sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware`

then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to have any effect, still hangs once it reaches `Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic`

Comment: Looks like you were on the right track though, given what it was configuring (`grub-efi-amd64`) had efi in the name I tried removing the execute flag from `30_uefi-firmware`) and rerunning dpkg and it got farther, it setup `grub-efi-amd64` but now it's hanging on `Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.12+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12) ...Installing for x86_64-efi platform.` - but at least it's progress, thanks!

Comment: Before seeing your last comment I had rebooted and reran dpkg configure and for some reason it made it through `grub-efi-amd64-signed` fine (and none other followed). I was then able to run `apt upgrade` without issue so if you edit your answer to suggest removing the execute flag on both `30_os-prober` and `30_uefi-firmware` I'll mark it as accepted. (Also I'll make that suggested change to `30_uefi-firmware` you linked when I toggle the execute flag back on). Thanks much!

Comment: @Exupery --  edited answer

Comment: Sometimes it is not a bug in os_prober et. al. In my case, I had a bad duplicate of my (dual) boot drive connected to the system and this was messing up grub's probing logic. If anyone is in a similar situation, remember to re-enable the prober using `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` as well when you're done.